# how to draw an grid box dynamically for snap to grid using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am developing dragging functionality with snap to grid option. I was able to drag with snap to grid option but struggling in how to draw an grid system in html.

I have an drop down with available snap to grid size(like 10*10,20*20,30*30) and then one parent container div inside I have placed four boxes which are dragging with snap to grid. I was able to calculate the XY positions with snap to grid size. But I want draw an grid box based on user selects the grid size value.

For creating grid box, is it possible to set an backgroundImage for an parent container? or do we need to create an extra html element?

HTML Code:

```
<label style="margin-right:5px;">Snap To Grid : </label>
<select id="snapToGrid">
    <option value="10">10*10</option>
    <option value="20">20*20</option>
    <option value="30">30*30</option>
    <option value="40">40*40</option>
    <option value="50">50*50</option>
</select>

<div id="status">

</div>
<br />
<div id="parentContainer">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="box" style="left:0px;top:0px;">
            1stBox
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="left:104px;top:0px;">
            2ndBox
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="left:0px;top:104px;">
            3rdBox
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="left:104px;top:104px;">
            4thBox
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var mousedown = false;
    var mouseStartXposition;
    var zoomContainer = $("#container");
    var $box;
    var snapToGridContainer = $("#snapToGrid");
    var snapToGridValue;
    $(".box").mousedown(function(event){
        mousedown = true;            
        $box = $(this);
        snapToGridValue = parseInt(snapToGridContainer.val());            
    });

    $("#parentContainer, .box").mouseup(function(){
        mousedown = false;
    });

    $("#parentContainer").mousemove(function(event){           
        if(mousedown){
            var clientX = event.clientX;
            var clientY = event.clientY;
            // Include Scroll Left and Top
            clientX = clientX + $("#container").scrollLeft();
            clientY = clientY + $("#container").scrollTop();

            clientX = clientX - zoomContainer.offset().left;
            clientY = clientY - zoomContainer.offset().top;

            var snapedX = clientX - (clientX % snapToGridValue);
            var snapedY = clientY - (clientY % snapToGridValue);

            //  apply to boxes
            $box.css({
                top:snapedY,
                left:snapedX
            })
        }
    });
```

});

I have attached JSFiddle link.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/aprakash290/Lzpxv9q0/)

I want to grid box like below on top of it the four boxes should be there.
[image: sampleimage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) as background

**UPDATE**

The percentage calculation is based on simple formula

Consider your div as 100% now divide this into *n* parts (grids) that becomes how much percentage of area each division will occupy in the original div , if you want to translate that into pixels you can multiply the result with the div's actual width(or height doesn't matter if we are talking of square divs) in pixels

For instance (assuming square grids only)
If grid is **2X2** then `100/2 = 50%`

And in pixels assuming container is `500px` wide
`grid_width = 50/100*500 ; //250px`

```js
  var mousedown = false;
  var mouseStartXposition;
  var zoomContainer = $("#container");
  var $box;
  var snapToGridContainer = $("#snapToGrid");
  var snapToGridValue = 10; // made 10 grid (first option) as default
 
  //handle changing of grid class and snap value
  function initGrid() {
    $('#parentContainer').removeClass();
    $('#parentContainer').addClass('grid g-'+$('#snapToGrid').val());

    snapToGridCount = parseInt(snapToGridContainer.val()); // how many grids

    //calc. the percentage of space a single grid would occupy
    snapToGridPct = 100/snapToGridCount; //%
    //convert that into absolute pixels considering our container div size
    //ie. how much space in pixel a grid would occuppy
    snapToGridValue = (snapToGridPct/100) * 500; // 500 is width(and height) of #parentContainer

    //for decimal results
    snapToGridValue = parseInt((snapToGridValue))
  }

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#snapToGrid').change(initGrid)

  $(".box").mousedown(function(event) {
    mousedown = true;
    $box = $(this);

    //UI feedback
    $box.css('cursor', 'pointer')
    $box.mouseup(function () {
      $(this).css('cursor', 'inherit');
    })
  });

  $("#parentContainer, .box").mouseup(function() {
    mousedown = false;
  });

  $("#parentContainer").mousemove(function(event) {
    if (mousedown) {
      var clientX = event.clientX;
      var clientY = event.clientY;

      // Include Scroll Left and Top
      clientX = clientX + $("#container").scrollLeft();
      clientY = clientY + $("#container").scrollTop();

      clientX = clientX - zoomContainer.offset().left;
      clientY = clientY - zoomContainer.offset().top;
 
      var snapedX = clientX - (clientX % snapToGridValue);
      var  snapedY = clientY - (clientY % snapToGridValue);

      $box.css({
        top: snapedY,
        left: snapedX
      })
    }
  });

  initGrid();//start on page load
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: top left;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

#parentContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* important otherwise we need to do math for the border calculation*/
}

.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(0deg, #CCC 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px),
   linear-gradient(90deg, #CCC 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px), 
   linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px), 
   linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px)
 
}

/* pixel % calculated as : 100 / number_of_grids; */

.g-10 {
  background-size: 10% 10%, 10% 10%, 10% 10%, 10% 10%;
}

.g-20 {
  background-size: 5% 5%, 5% 5%, 5% 5%, 5% 5%;
}

.g-30 {
  background-size: 3.3% 3.3%, 3.3% 3.3%, 3.3% 3.3%, 3.3% 3.3%;
}

.g-40 {
  background-size: 2.5% 2.5%, 2.5% 2.5%, 2.5% 2.5%, 2.5% 2.5%;
}

.g-50 {
  background-size: 2% 2%, 2% 2%, 2% 2%, 2% 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label style="margin-right:5px;">Snap To Grid : </label> <span id="lod"></span>
<select id="snapToGrid">
  <option value="10" selected>10*10</option>
  <option value="20">20*20</option>
  <option value="30">30*30</option>
  <option value="40">40*40</option>
  <option value="50">50*50</option>
</select>

<div id="parentContainer" class="grid g-10">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="box" style="left:0px;top:0px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For background-size you have used % to specify the size. How to change this value for 20*20,30*30..50*50 snap size. Is it possible to use linear-gradient() as transparent? Because I am using white background and I want grid border color should be black or gray.

Comment: Hi it's a simple calculation and yes you can use rgba() for transparency, I'll update the code

Comment: Thanks. The even number grid lines border thickness is lit bit high. How to make all grid boxes having same thickness.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention some peculiarity-  the red box won't overlap the grids when you select 30x30 is due the fact that separation among grids gets to 3.3% or 17px (as we have #parentContainer width 500px) since 17's multipl. table is 17,34,51,68,85,102,119..which has all numbers as either primes or odds, the box wont sit perfectly between given 2 opposite left and right grid-lines as the distance is either more or less than 100px (but we need 100px) so you might need to adjust the width of box to make it fit. No such problem happens when grid separation is a multiple of 10 or 5